# Arduino GET request parsing large data

Tags: http, parsing, arduino, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to parse hexadecimal values that I receive from a web server after converting an image to a 1 bit BMP image then converting that BMP image to hexadecimal values. This data is received by an Arduino nano IoT 33 via HTTP GET request. This data is basically used to update an eInk display that is attached to the Arduino. The goal is to update the display wirelessly with any image that I want. I am successfully able to send the data to my Arduino however, due to the size of the received data it takes a lot of time to parse this data. The Content-Length of the received data on average is 80540.

I have tried the code mentioned in the following discussion, however, the sheer size of the data makes the process slow to a point where the Arduino just doesn't do anything and my IDE crashes.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=49357.0

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=281897.0

I have attached a screenshot below which shows some parts of the data I receive.

Is there any way or any library that I can use to parse this large data and save it into an array that can then be used to update the eInk display? A response will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You are using a MCU with 32KB of SRAM running on 48MHz, this is just a wrong tool for the wrong job. Get an ESP32, which has 512KB SRAM and operated at 160/240MHz.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already pointed out, 32KB RAM is not enough to hold an average set of 80KB. Apart from choosing a different microcontroller, you could try to split your image into chunks (8K maybe?), have each chunk transferred in its own GET-request, and draw each each on your display before requesting the next chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Given the memory and CPU constraints there are several approaches that you can take. I assume that you can modify the server code for some of these (or place a proxy in the middle that modifies the response accordingly).

You may need to implement more than one of these to workaround the constraints of your board.

### Chunk the Response via the Client Request

The Arduino client can request a chunk of the data and process that chunk before requesting the next chunk. This could be either via a 'paged' request or use of the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

### Use a More Efficient Encoding in the Server Response

The sample response encodes a single octet as six characters (e.g. `0xff,`).

Changing to a binary response would reduce the example 80KB down to about 14KB. A simple binary dump could be returned. e.g. a HTTP response (with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header) could have a pure binary payload.

If you need the response to remain as text then even base 64 encoding will be more memory efficient than the current hexadecimal encoding.

### Use a Compressed Encoding in the Server Response (e.g. RLE)

This is not compressing the response payload (via HTTP compression) as the Arduino would probably not have the memory or CPU to handle this.

Instead a Run Length Encoding might compress the payload enough to fit into the memory footprint. An efficient RLE decoder should be able to work with a small amount of RAM/CPU.

RLE is often very suitable for compression of 1-bit images.

Answer (score 0):

I parse HTML data by this code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //physical mac address
byte myserver[] = { 199, 166, 222, 111}; //

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {

  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}

void loop() {

  delay(1000);
 
  if (client.connect(myserver, 8081)) {  
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /adress HTTP/1.0"); //GET request
    client.println(); //end of get request

  }
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed"); 
    Serial.println();
  }

  while (client.connected() && !client.available()) delay(100); 
  while (client.connected() || client.available()) { 

    char webdata = client.read(); 
     // parse webdata as string
  }

  Serial.println("disconnecting.");
  client.stop(); //stop client

}
```

I do it with W5100 ethernet shield